# Mac OS X as client to Windows Terminal Services?

Tags: windows, mac, terminal-services

Can a Mac OS X machine act as a client to Windows Terminal Services?

Specifically the following needs to work:

- Printing (printing from inside the terminal window should use the local Mac printer)

If possible:

- Some way to move files from the remote session to the local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am missing something. You can use [Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client).

It has all the same features of remote desktop for windows including printer and drive sharing.

Extracts from the official site:

> New Multiple Session Support gives Mac users simultaneous access to multiple Windows-based PCs or to a network server that hosts remote applications and files. Since it is a Universal application, Remote Desktop Connection Client 2 is compatible with the latest technologies on Windows and Mac platforms.
>
> Access and print from Windows applications to any printer that can be configured from your Mac.

Comment: You're not missing anything. Remote Desktop for Mac works fine. I use it on a regular basis.

Comment: @Larry That makes 2 of us. I use it daily.

Answer (score 3):

[CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.net/) may have the features you're looking for.

Comment: +1 Also a nice tool I wasn't aware of. Something I am planning to test for a few days.

Comment: Feels like good Mac software. Good option to the official Microsoft client.